# Terraform Error: Reference to undeclared resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, syntax, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run s3 replication in terraform which will be cross-regional. Most of my code is good but I am only getting 2 errors which I cannot seem to solve.

Part of my main s3.tf is

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_replica-us-west-2" {
  description             = "S3 master key replica us-west-2"
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
  enable_key_rotation     = "true"
}

module "s3_replica" {
  source = "git@github.com:xxx"

  providers = {
    aws     = "aws.us-west-2"
  }

  name                  = "s3_replica"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3_replica"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3_replica-us-west-2.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm
}

module "s3" {
  source                = "git@github.com:xxxx"
  name                  = "s3"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm

  replication_configuration = {
    role = aws_iam_role.s3_replication.arn

      rules = {
         id = "replicate_to_${local.s3_replica}"
         prefix = ""
         status = "Enabled"

        destination = {
          bucket = lookup.module.s3_replica.bucket_arn
          replica_kms_key_id = lookup.s3_replica_arn
          }
        }

      source_selection_criteria = {
          sse_kms_encrypted_objects = {
            enabled = true
          }
        }
  }
```

and the part of my replication configuration block in the module I use is:

```
dynamic "replication_configuration" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.replication_configuration)) == 0 ? [] : [var.replication_configuration]

    content {
      role = replication_configuration.value.role

      dynamic "rules" {
        for_each = replication_configuration.value.rules

        content {
          id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
          priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
          prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
          status   = lookup(rules.value, "status", null)

          dynamic "destination" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]

            content {
              bucket             = lookup(destination.value, "bucket", null)
              storage_class      = lookup(destination.value, "storage_class", null)
              replica_kms_key_id = lookup(destination.value, "replica_kms_key_id", null)
              account_id         = lookup(destination.value, "account_id", null)
            }
          }

          dynamic "source_selection_criteria" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]

            content {

              dynamic "sse_kms_encrypted_objects" {
                for_each = length(keys(lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {})]

                content {

                  enabled = sse_kms_encrypted_objects.value.enabled
                }
              }
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run terraform init... it works.
But when I run terraform plan I get the error:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on s3.tf line 108, in module "s3":
 108:           bucket = lookup.module.s3_replica.bucket_arn

A managed resource "lookup" "module" has not been declared in the root module.


Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on s3.tf line 109, in module "s3":
 109:           replica_kms_key_id = lookup.s3_replica-us-west-2_arn

A managed resource "lookup" "s3_replica_arn" has not been declared
in the root module.
```

Now I do not know why I get these errors..

Comment: What is `lookup.module`? Such syntax is incorrect in terraform. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Marcin i want to reference the arn of my destination bucket that is and will be created by module s3_replica (see in code).. I want to reference that.

Comment: So you want to reference values of a module, before the module actually exists? You can't do this. First you fully create module, and then in the root module, you can reference it outputs.

Comment: @Marcin Oh, so as I am creating the "destination bucket which is the s3_replica" through the module.. I will have to first create it? and once that is done then I will be able to reference that arn? for both the replica bucket and the replica key I will create? .. I want to reference the ARN as seen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, your `s3_replica` bucket is created in `module.s3`, and you want to access its ARN to initialize the `module.s3`. Sadly, you can't do this, as you can't reference module outputs before the module is fully created.

One way to overcome this issue, is to create `s3_replica` first, and then pass it to  `module.s3`. Below is just an example, probably need many further modifications:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_replica" {
  bucket = "my-replication-bucket-23223"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "s3_replica" {
  description             = "KMS for replication"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
}

module "s3" {

  # 
  #

  replication_configuration = {
    role = aws_iam_role.s3_replication.arn

      rules = {
         id = "replicate_to_${local.s3_replica}"
         prefix = ""
         status = "Enabled"

        destination = {
          bucket             = resource.aws_s3_bucket.s3_replica.arn
          replica_kms_key_id = resource.aws_kms_key.s3_replica.arn
          }
        }

      source_selection_criteria = {
          sse_kms_encrypted_objects = {
            enabled = true
          }
        }
  }
```

I would recommend having a look at [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html)  in TF docs. It explains, with examples, how to work with modules.